# include feature.xml in spfx webpart

Tags: spfx-webparts

The DOcs at https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/basics/notes-on-solution-packaging say that I can include a feature.xml with my spfx webpart to have sharepoint resources provisioned for a webpart. They dont spell out clearly how to do so.  How can i use this to have a custom list created each time my webpart is deployed. Any examples anywhere?
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/SPFX-and-Feature-XML

Comment: thanks, I see the pnp team did a webcats on this as well.